# Check Multiple Radio values with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've 10 question and each have 4 options, i want to check radio values, whether it is correct or not with the result stored in database when a user submit the form.

thanks in advance...

```
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     foreach( $_POST as $key=>$val){
     if($row['answer'] == $val){ echo "Correct";} 
     else{ echo "Incorrect";
     }
```

Comment: show your code also. What have you tried?

Comment: Don't just say what you want . Say what have you tried and what problem you faced?

Answer (score 1):

@broken_heart is right. you should provide your code. then some body will guide you.... anyway, this is the one way.. try once...

Steps:

1. assign different names with auto increment for each radio button group. name should be like this **radio_name[$i]** .... here $i is auto increment...
2. submit the form
3. Get value like this..

   ```
    $radio_values=$_POST['radion_name'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($radio_values);$i++)
    {
    $radio_value= $radio_values[$i];
    }
   ```